# How to properly use tag dispatching to pick a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to implement a set of mutex and lock classes for an embedded system. I've never used tag dispatching before, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. The description included in the boost documentation simply has this:

```
struct input_iterator_tag { };
```

and uses it to pick a specialized template function. I don't have a template, I just want to pick a specific constructor based on the presence of a tag:

```
// in mutex.h:

struct TryLock { };
// defined nowhere, i.e. there's no cpp file for this:
extern TryLock try_lock; 

template<typename MutexType>
class ScopedLock
{
  public:
    ScopedLock(MutexType& mtx) : m_mtx(mtx), m_acquired(true)
    {
      m_mtx.lock();
    }
    ScopedLock(MutexType& mtx, TryLock) : m_mtx(mtx)
    {
      m_acquired = m_mtx.tryLock();
    }
  ...
}
```

and somewhere in my code I have a mutex which I want to lock:

```
Mutex mtx;
ScopedLock<Mutex> lock(mtx, try_lock);
```

This compiles fine and works. I'm just curious if I can get rid of the `extern TryLock try_lock;`, as I have the impression that it's somewhat superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need the extern declaration for try_lock, if you replace its usage in the lock constructor call with a temporary:

```
Mutex mtx;
ScopedLock<Mutex> lock(mtx, TryLock());
```

Otherwise the compiler will pass a copy of try_lock to your constructor, at which point it will want to link against it.

When the standard library needs to do this, it uses `constexpr`:

```
struct piecewise_construct_t { };
constexpr piecewise_construct_t piecewise_construct = piecewise_construct_t();
```

Comment: I had that idea before, but differs from the examples of tag dispatching I've seen around and requires extra typing of the parantheses. Wouldn't the compiler optimize away the second argument anyway if the method is inlined?

Comment: I'd certainly hope it would optimize it away, but what I don't fully understand is why things are working with the undefined extern.  Is it just a case of luck with the optimizer, or is there something in the standard that allows it to work?

Comment: I'd say it's optimizer luck. If the address of the struct is needed, this would generate a linker error. But as the "contents" of a tag used in this way are never needed, that's a very unlikely situation.

Comment: @razeh: I think your added standard library example is what I'm looking for. I understand that `piecewise_construct` is what is passed to the constructor, which accepts a `piecewise_construct_t`?

Comment: @Christoph you're correct --- the constructor takes a piecewise_construct_t.