# Constructor with template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor

I have a `Dynamic` class that can store different types : `int`, `double`, `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<double>`, etc. I have about 50 of such types.

I would like my Dynamic type to have a constructor where we give two informations:

- The type to be stored
- Arguments used to construct the type inside the Dynamic class

I am looking forward to something such as

```
const Dynamic x<std::vector<double>>{10};
```

to construct in place a Dynamic object that has a `std::vector<double>` of length 10.

PS: I am allowed to use C++11 and I am not allowed to use RTTI

Comment: You can't have explicit template arguments with constructors. And why can't you use RTTI yet have to do something like this?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are trying to achieve, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960849/c-template-constructor) on templated constructors may be relevant. Essentially, you cannot provide template arguments for a constructor, they must all be deduced.

Comment: @Passer By: I am designing a library and some of my clients compile without RTTI. And I need such a `Dynamic` object to load JSON files for instance.

Comment: @François: Thanks. I guess I need to forget about this constructor. Too bad.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775285/how-to-properly-use-tag-dispatching-to-pick-a-constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor template arguments must be deduced. They cannot be provided explicitly. You can get around this by providing a type tag which encodes the wanted template argument and passing it as an additional constructor argument. For example :

```
#include <utility>  // For std::forward

struct foo
{
    // Helper tag type
    template<class T>
    struct type_tag {};

    // The template argument T is deduced from type_tag<T>
    template<class T, class ... Args>
    foo(type_tag<T>, Args&&... p_args)
    {
        T value{ std::forward<Args>(p_args)... };
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Provide a type tag so the template argument can be deduced
    foo bar{ foo::type_tag<int>{}, 5 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't mind putting the type info next to `Dynamic` rather than the variable name you can do this with variadic args:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Dynamic
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Dynamic(Args... args) : data_(args...)
    {
    }

    T data_;
};

int main()
{
    const Dynamic<std::vector<double>> x{10};

    std::cout << x.data_.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of having a dynamic type

Comment: @Passer By Can you elaborate on how it's different putting the type left of the variable name rather than right of it? The OP's original code is still all static types.

Comment: OP seems to want something like `std::variant`